# Qual a diferença do uso do "equals" vs == no LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Conforme citado acima, quando digo `equals` do LINQ to Entities estou me referindo especificamente à palavra reservada de C# e não ao `Equals()` do `System.Object`.

*Fonte:* [equals (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/equals)

O exemplo a seguir retorna todos os produtos vermelhos.

```
String color = "Red";
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    var query =
        from product in context.Products
        where product.Color == color
        select new
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber,
            ListPrice = product.ListPrice
        };

    foreach (var product in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", product.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Product number: {0}", product.ProductNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("List price: ${0}", product.ListPrice);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

*Fonte:* [Exemplos de sintaxe de expressão de consulta: filtragem | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-expression-syntax-examples-filtering)

**Dúvida:** Qual a diferença ou impacto ao alterar `==` para `equals` ? Ao fazer essa alteração o select é montado da mesma forma?

**Obs:** não me refiro ao método `.Equals()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode usar `equals`, daria erro porque o `equals` é uma cláusula do `join` que você não está usando.

Em um `join` você usa para fazer a ligação entre duas sequências de dados usando o campo de uma delas contra o campo da outra, desta forma fica claro que é isso e não uma comparação de igualdade pura e simples que retornaria um booleano como resultado, é um mecanismo diferente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Maniero, eu estava imaginando que o equals na verdade poderia sempre ser utilizado para criar uma consulta no linq, mas não havia me atentado ao fato de que ele é especificamente utilizado junto à clausula join.